# Scale Texture based on the start and end position

Tags: java, android, libgdx

In my LibGdx based game, I need to scale the image from the start till the end position. The end position varies as the time goes. Hence the image has to be scaled based on the end position.

Could you please assist me in scaling the texture based on start and end position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Scene2D with Stage and Actors, you can create [Image actor](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Image.html) with you texture and

```
myImageActor.setBounds(startX, startY, widthFromMyEndPosition, heightFromMyEndPosition)
```

Or, you can use [spriteBatch.draw(Texture texture,float x,float y,float width, float height)](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/SpriteBatch.html#draw-com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture-float-float-float-float-) at the same way.